# Nexus 10 isn't showing up under Computer -> Devices and Removable Storage - [Solved] new USB to micro USB cable only charges, but no data transfer

Tags: usb, data-transfer, charging

Recently, my Nexus 10 isn't showing up under Computer -> Devices and Removable Storage when I plug it into my computer with a USB to micro USB cable.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that it had it do with changing the USB to micro USB cable.

The cable that came with my Nexus 10 was tearing due to bending.

I found a Logitech USB to micro USB cable lying around, and used that.

I didn't think that there were problems with that cable because it was charging the device fine.

I then found some information from a metafilter post http://ask.metafilter.com/197249/All-micro-usb-cables-are-not-created-equal:

> Why does the motorola branded micro usb cable that came with my droid
> phone both charge *AND* transfer data, but generic micro usb cables
> will only charge the phone?
>
> Recently got a Motorola Droid phone.
>
> It included a motorola-branded micro usb cable.
>
> I can use it to charge the phone and also transfer data back and forth
> between the phone and a computer.
>
> I just bought some cheap, non-branded micro usb cables to sprinkle
> around home and work so I'd always be able to charge the phone.
>
> However, I've noticed that the non-branded micro usb cables will NOT
> transfer data, only charge.
>
> Both cables appear to have the same number of metal contacts on each
> end.
>
> So what gives, why does the motorola cable allow data transfer and the
> generics do not?

---

> The connector has the same amount of pins, but the cable itself probably has less wires soldered to those pins.
>
> The Droid's cable apparently has an extra pin connected, presumably
> for data transfer.

---

> I have a generic usb cord that has two heads - one for data transfer
> and one for charging (common connection to the computer, different
> connections to the phone).
>
> I think that yes, sometimes people just want to charge their phones.

---

> I've asked my sister, who is not only a Droid Bionic owner, but also
> the supervisor of the mobile phone department at the local branch of a
> large American big box electronic retailer.
>
> She is going to see if she can find the answer, and let me know later.
>
> Just heard back from my sister, and she says that some of the cheaper
> USB cables they sell are "charge only".
>
> So that may be part of the issue.

The stock Nexus 10 USB to micro USB cable, and a bought Cirago USB to micro USB cable made my Nexus 10 show up, but the Logitech USB to micro USB cable did not.

It seems that USB to micro USB cables can differ, as some cables only charge, but don't transfer data.